# float a button to the right side

Tags: html, css

i have a menu button in the left side of website, i can't float it to the right side, i tried display properties thousands times
here my css:

```
    .menu-button {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999999999;
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 0;
     width: 2.5em;
     height: 2.25em;
     border: none;
     text-indent: 2.5em;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     color: transparent;
     background: transparent;
     outline: 0;
     }
```

and here is the site you can check the inspact element by the way : wwww.takchinsaffron.com

Comment: Have you tried `float:right`? Or `right: 0` since the position is fixed

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yeah ofcourse in the first tries:D i set display:inline-block or display:inline and float:right but didn't work

Comment: Use `left:100%` or `right: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `right: 0` to your selector:

```
.menu-button {
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `left:100%` to your selector:

```
.menu-button {
    left: 100%;
}
```

If the element goes out of bounds, try adding `transform:translate`

```
.menu-button {
    left: 100%;
    transform:translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Comment: @LGSon Why `2.5em`?

Comment: It's the width of the element, `width: 2.5em;`

Comment: @LGSon I see.I'll try this next time, thanks for the tip